# Mongodb .net updating one of the embedded documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an `orders` and each has `transactions` embedded.

```
{
    _id: orderId1,
    other_fields: something else,
    transactions: [
       {
           _id: someId,
           price: 25,
           status: 1
       },
       {
           _id: someId2,
           price: 30,
           status: 0
       }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to change the status of one of the transactions(lets say: someId2). How can i do that?

Both orders and transactions are models with transaction as `ICollection<Transaction>`

Also, is it possible without using any magic string?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the below query

```
db.collection.update({"transactions._id":"someId2"}, {$set:{"transactions.$.status":2}})
```

First part of the query is to find the record and the second part is to update the document, this update is [positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) update

Please note that positional update will be done for only one matching document. Even if we have multiple documents matching the query only one document will be updated, so to safely use the positional update give the maximum condition in find part of the query to retrieve the unique matching document, say in this case the modified query is

```
db.collection.update({"_id":"orderId1", "transactions._id":"someId2"}, {$set:{"transactions.$.status":1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one way this can be done using the C# driver:

```
await mongoCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    o => o.Id == orderId1 && x.Transactions.Any(t => t.Id == someId2),
    Builders<Order>.Update.Set(x => x.Transactions[-1].Status, someStatus));
```

The use of `-1` as an indexer is the key to all of this - it's essentially the translation from C# to the [Positional Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). This instructs the driver to use the index that was matched in the call to `x.Transactions.Any` in my example. I'm sure there are alternatives to using `Any`, but given that you're searching by a unique ID, this should work for your setup.